# Augmenting an interface that lives in a declared namespace in TypeScript

Tags: angularjs, typescript, typescript-typings

I want to augment the `IHttpPromise<T>` inside the declared angular namespace (from "@types/angular"). So that I'll be able to write `$http.then(...).myCustomMethod(...)`.

I was able to augment interfaces in the global context easily by just writing:

```
interface JQuery {
    $custom: string;
}
```

For interfaces inside namespaces, the same doesn't work obviously. Tried several things like declaring the `angular` namespace again and putting the augmented interface inside, but that and other numerous variations didn't work.

Note that I'm not using (external) modules.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found the solution. Even if you're not using modules, you'll have to do the following in a separate declaration file:

```
import { IHttpPromise } from '@types/angular';

declare module '@types/angular' {
    interface IHttpPromise<T> {
        myCustomMethod(): something;
    }
}
```

The import statement's content itself is not important. We have to do an import to make TS treat this file as a module for this to work. So this would've also worked:

```
import * as angular from '@types/angular';
```

This is documented at the end [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-merging.html).